# Open vscode from script in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, kubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create script to open VSCode in the current directory but I am not abe to do it for folder consist of spaces.

For example if location is 'home/documents/code'. it is able to open correctly, but if location is 'home/documents/code folder' it does not open the 'code folder' in vscode.

Command that I am using

```
code -n $PWD
```

This command works fine if folder does not have spaces
I have tried to enter the $PWD in double quotes but on executing the script it does not opens the folder in the location

```
code -n \"$PWD\"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont use \ before " you can open it
you need to write
`code -n "$PWD"`
i tested on my terminal and my pwd was `/home/aazerra/Untitled Folder` and worked

if you read [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/439199/15-special-characters-you-need-to-know-for-bash/) you can see this

> If you enclose the text in quotation marks (“…”), this prevents Bash from acting on most of the special characters, and they just print. One notable exception, though, is the dollar sign ($). It still functions as the character for variable expressions, so you can include the values from variables in your output.

Comment: Thanks it worked